# CT logs for non browser applications

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, certificate-transparency

Most what I read on CT logs is about browsers checking the logs for websites.
But what about normal applications or updates for operating systems (like apt-get over https, windows/osx updates  ...)

Is checking CT logs mandatory for those too?
Is it up to the program developer to implement this?

Comment: Browsers (and other clients, if implemented) don't check logs; they check the SCT(s) created by the logs and either inserted in the cert by the CA or added as a TLS extension by the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it up to the program developer to implement this?

that's correct, it is up to developer to include CT log support in non-browser applications. CT Logs are required by CA/**Browser** Forum and this covers only web browsers.